# TextInput to make.keys function in Shiny app (psych package)

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing a psychometrics app in Shiny. I am fairly new but I am coping with most of the problems. However, what I can't seem to find is how to feed the input from textInput box into the keys.list argument of the make.keys function. Here is what I have so far:

Server:

```
scale <- reactive({
data <- data_fa()
key.list <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(input$test, "[,]")))
make.keys(ncol(data), key.list)
})
```

Ui:

```
textInput("test", "Test:", "1")
```

I am not posting the entire code, because it is too long and unrelated to the issue. I tried all kinds of solutions, but I've only got so far. The idea of the function is to make a matrix of one or more columns and rows with 1,0, or -1 as values. This code gets me to a point where each number filled in the textInput makes another column while it should fill a row instead.

I've also tried with shinyIncubator and matrixInput. It works, but the problem is that I can't add columns on demand there.

So, any help would be very appreciated!